# Is there any way to change the default file name of the backup file while taking the backup with "pg_basebackup.exe" tool in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

While taking the backup in PostgreSQL using pg_basebackup.exe tool the default backup file name is **base.tar**.

Ex: `pg_basebackup -D backup -Ft -z -P`

The above command will take the backup and create the file name **base.tar.gz** in backup directory.

Is there any way to change the default file name from base.tar to myfilename.tar ?

Comment: No, there is no such option. But what keeps you from simply renaming it afterwards? The result of a pg_basebackup is typically used to initialize a new clone and for that it makes sense to name the output directory `base` as that is the name required.

Comment: Just wanted to change the file name with timestamp so that it will be meaningful and it will be easily tracked. I am invoking "pg_basebackup.exe" though java process builder.

Comment: Why not put the timestamp into the name of the **directory**, which under `-Ft` you have no choice but to specify?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jjanes. I already have done that